# Nested repeat tag alignment issue

Tags: apex, visualforce

I am using Nested repeat Tag for product and values alignment. But it doesnt work correctly.

Below is my code,

```
<apex:repeat value="{!prods}" var="f">  //contains product names (has 4 values// Truveda, Zydelig, Stribild, Viread)             
               <apex:repeat value="{!cp.cpd}" var="ct"> (has 2 values // Truveda, Zydelig)                    
                    <apex:outputPanel rendered="{!IF(f == ct.Product_vod__r.External_ID_GILD_E__c, 'true','false')}">
                      <TD align="center"> {!f} , {!ct.Product_vod__r.External_ID_GILD_E__c} </td>
                    </apex:outputPanel>

              </apex:repeat> 
   </apex:repeat>
```

In below Screenshot, i dont have Stribild and Viread values, so its skips the 'td' and aligns in first two columns. But it should be aligned to 2nd and 4th column. I understand why it works this way but is there a way to achieve this.?

[image]

if i make the 'td' outside of outputpanel (suggested by Dan in comments), it looks like below,

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try updating the order of the repeat tags so that they look like this. This way you should be able to iterate more effectively between the two products to check if they match so you can display the values under the correct column.

```
<apex:repeat value="prod" var="ct"> // value in 2
    <apex:repeat value="otherprod" var"f"> value in 4
        <td align="center">
            <apex:outputPanel rendered="{!IF(f == ct.Product_vod__r.External_ID_GILD_E__c, 'true','false')}"> 
                {!f} , {!ct.Product_vod__r.External_ID_GILD_E__c} 
            </apex:outputPanel>
        </td>
    </apex:repeat>
</apex:repeat>
```

Comment: Hi Dan, Thanks for the reply. I have already tried your suggestion but dint solve the issue. still alignment is not working properly. I will update the question to show the problem with your approach.

Comment: have you tried  changing the order of the repeat tags. I have updated my answer to show the code for that.